# Why is this class not JSon serializable?

Tags: python, json

I have this class in Python 3.5:

```
class DataPoint(object):

    def __init__(self, time, value):
        self.time = time
        self.value = value
```

And when I try to create a JSon from an instance, doing:

```
json.dumps( intance_of_datapoint )
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: < DataPoint object at 0x0123 > is not JSon Serializable
```

So I have tried to improve the class overwritting the **repr** method, like this:

```
class DataPoint(object):

    def __init__(self, time, value):
        self.time = time
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)

    __repr__ = __str__
```

By doing that I get:

```
TypeError: {"value":52.29, "time":1} is not JSon serializable.
```

Can you guys helps me undestand why?
I'm pretty lost here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to convert your instance in python dict and then you can dump that dict in json.dumps(instance_dict). because, as json have its own data types, and python user defined class cannot serialize to json.

Comment: That did the trick!
I wonder why the Json encoder doesn't do the job and call ._ _dict_ _ for every object it finds.

Comment: You can upvote my answer if it helps you.